# Refresh Parent function widget from child class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wan to refresh parent component from child class,

I read some articles but still confusing because parent is `function` and child is `class`

I appreciate your any help thank you very much.

Parent function component

```
export default function HeaderLinks(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <ChildWidget myHeaderLink={this}></ChildWidget>
```

Child Class

```
class AuthWidget extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  }
  refreshParent(){
        this.props.myHeaderLink.setState() ..??? maybe I need something equivalent to setState()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a very small sample to display this useCase. You can check it here.
Just pass prop and onClick I handle it on the parent which update the state of parent and eventually that state change leads to the Re-renders of the component.
https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-dubinsky-w32dz?file=/src/App.js

Click on Button "Change parent Property" changes the parent state from "Hello World" to "Bye World"

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.I can solve the problem  I need to know `useState` more

Comment: you can refer this official docs for reading all react hooks which works with react function components https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html